# Как работает маршрутизация при передаче сообщения от белого IP к серому?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, nat, сетевое-программирование, маршрутизатор

Когда я со своего устройства делаю запрос к ru.stackoverflow.com, то мой маршрутизатор (серый IP) благодаря NAT пересылает сообщение на маршрутизатор провайдера, при этом подменяет `192.168.1.X` на `172.17.135.11`, далее провайдер уже подменяет `172.17.135.11` на свой белый IP `5.16.126.234` и передаёт запрос на белый IP ru.stackoverflow.com.

**Как ru.stackoverflow.com понимает, что запрос нужно отдать именно мне**, если мой IP для WAN это IP провайдера? Какие данные находятся в сообщении, которое приходит на эту сеть маршрутизаторов, чтобы попасть именно на моё устройство?
[image: Схема сети между моими устройствами и ru.stackoverflow.com]

Comment: А он провайдеру и отвечает. Провойдер же хранит таблицу трансляции (хост-порт) и по ответу на  порт подменяет IP (и порт), переправляя пакет вам

Comment: @avp да, это я понимаю. Но какие данные он даёт провайдеру, чтобы провайдер понял, что ответ предназначается именно мне?

Comment: Никаких. Он отвечает провайдеру, о вас он ничего не знает. О вас знает только провайдер (NAT)

Comment: Рискну добавить пару слов в Ваш разговор: никакие. Сайт отвечает провайдеру точно так же, как если бы компьютер провайдера был просто компьютером с запущенным на нём браузером. Вся "магия" по которой провайдер понимает, что ответ нужнопередать Вам заключается втом, что в NAT есть таблица с "запросами" и по ней обратно отправляется "ответ". Ключем в этой таблице (то есть параметром, по которому один пользователь отличается от другого) является номер открытого со стороны провайдера порта.

Comment: @S.H., строго говоря пара IP-port. Т.е. c одним портом провайдера могут общаться много внешних хостов

Comment: @avp - да, справледливо. Тут еще очень полезно было бы добавить, что "магия" просиходит в процедуре accept при установлении tcp - соединения, и в процессе accept'а "половинка" tcp -  соединения (то есть адрес:порт получателя) дополняется до "полного" соединения, то есть "адрес:порт получателя - адрес:порт отправителя"

Comment: @S.H. Вы ответили на мой вопрос, спасибо!